# Class not found Error while connecting Amazon AWS Athena to R-Server

Tags: r, jdbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to connect R-Server to Athena. But unable to do so. I have followed the guide from here :  https://www.r-bloggers.com/interacting-with-amazon-athena-from-r/

While running the Code:

```
URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil,method="curl",mode="wb")


library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(rJava)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", fil, identifier.quote="'")
```

I'm running into this error

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

I have also reffered to the previous question posted on Stackoverflow regarging this but it didnt't help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-amazon-athena/

It worked with me :)

Regards.

Comment: Hi. i followed that tutorial itself. But im still facing "Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found" Error. Is it because I'm running Java 1.7 ? And as per AWS documentation I should be running V1.8?